# Regexp to match only first occurrence starting from top of the text

Tags: regex, function, filter, pattern-matching, alteryx

I'm working on extracting specif string set after matching a pattern but results are not as expected. Instead of first occurrence starting from top of the text file the function picks very last occurrence.

Function:

```
[\n\r].*Sent:\s*([^\n\r]*)
```

Sample text:

> From: Y Sent: Monday, November 6, 2018 6:38 AM To: X
>
> BLA BLA
>
> Thank you,
>
> From: X Sent: Monday, November 5, 2018 8:38 AM To: Y
>
> Hi Y BLA
>
> Thanks,

Expected results:

```
Monday, November 6, 2018 6:38 AM
```

Curently returns:

```
 Monday, November 5, 2018 8:38 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Try this:

```
Sent:\s?(.*?)\sTo:
```

This looks for `'Sent'`, a `colon`, an optional White `Space`, then it creates `Group 1`, matching any number of `any char` until it reaches a White `Space` and '`To:`'.

If you set the global flag, it will match both dates, otherwise just the first.

The date will be in `Group 1`.

Answer (score 2):

The first occurrence is not being matched because you start your regex with `[\n\r]` which matches a newline and is not present before the first line in your example data.

To get your matches, you can omit `[\n\r].*` from the beginning and add `To:` at the end. If you don't use the global flag you will get only the first occurence and your match is in the first capturing group.

```
Sent:\s*([^\n\r]*) To:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0QAH5d/1)